# Count each occurrence of a random number

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm not too good at Java (just started learning it recently). What i have is this method:

```
String gInfo(){
   String[] Behavior = {"Sleeping", "Running home", "Studying", "playing pool", "walking to class"};
       int rNum = (int) (Math.random() * Behavior.length);
       return Behavior[rNum];
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is figure out how to calculate the number of times each array element occurs and turn it into a percentage.

Comment: How is your code related to counting? The code picks one element and returns it. Not multiple and no counting.

Comment: I loop it in the main class (separate from this one) to display 20 random results.

Answer (score 0):

To get it done quickly, you should have a separate data structure such as another array of integers. Those integers should be mapped to represent the elements in the Behaviors array.

I would also create the array of behaviors outside of that function because everything it is called, the array is recreated.
And... I would have that function '`gInfo`' return an int instead of a String because what good would a string be if you were to map the outcomes to an array of integers.

```
 String[] behavior = {"Sleeping", "Running home", "Studying", "playing  
 pool", "walking to class"};


 int[] count = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

When a random int is returned, then do this:

```
count[i] = count[i]++;
```

If you were to do it probably in a better way, create a class called behavior. Create an instance of this class for any behavior you wish. Inside the class, you would have a counter.